# Android - Problems with a Array<Bitmap>

Tags: android, arrays, gridview, bitmap

On the activity when i'm trying to save my downloaded image on a asyinc task:

```
                    URL url;
                    try {
                        url = new URL("http://example/URL");
                         try {
                            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());


                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    imagenes.add(bmp);


                    discotecaslist.add(map);
```

i had this error:

```
01-14 19:40:13.906: E/AndroidRuntime(31390): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-14 19:40:13.906: E/AndroidRuntime(31390): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error      occured while executing doInBackground()
01-14 19:40:13.906: E/AndroidRuntime(31390):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-14 19:40:13.906: E/AndroidRuntime(31390):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
01-14 19:40:13.906: E/AndroidRuntime(31390):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
01-14 19:40:13.906: E/AndroidRuntime(31390):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
01-14 19:40:13.906: E/AndroidRuntime(31390):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-14 19:40:13.906: E/AndroidRuntime(31390):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-14 19:40:13.906: E/AndroidRuntime(31390):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-14 19:40:13.906: E/AndroidRuntime(31390):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
01-14 19:40:13.906: E/AndroidRuntime(31390): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 19:40:13.906: E/AndroidRuntime(31390):    at     com.example.apparty.TabDiscotecas$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(TabDiscotecas.java:195)
01-14 19:40:13.906: E/AndroidRuntime(31390):    at     com.example.apparty.TabDiscotecas$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(TabDiscotecas.java:1)
01-14 19:40:13.906: E/AndroidRuntime(31390):    at     android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-14 19:40:13.906: E/AndroidRuntime(31390):    at     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-14 19:40:13.906: E/AndroidRuntime(31390):    ... 4 more
01-14 19:40:14.166: D/qdmemalloc(31390): ion: Unmap buf  base:0x6cc53000 size:1216512
01-14 19:40:14.166: D/qdmemalloc(31390): ion: Unmap buf  base:0x6ca4d000 size:4096
01-14 19:40:14.166: D/qdmemalloc(31390): ion: Unmap buf  base:0x6d88e000 size:1216512
01-14 19:40:14.166: D/qdmemalloc(31390): ion: Unmap buf  base:0x6cb4c000 size:4096
01-14 19:40:14.166: D/qdmemalloc(31390): ion: Unmap buf  base:0x6e1af000 size:1216512
01-14 19:40:14.166: D/qdmemalloc(31390): ion: Unmap buf  base:0x6cb4e000 size:4096
01-14 19:40:14.186: D/qdmemalloc(31390): ion: Unmap buf  base:0x6cf52000 size:8355840
01-14 19:40:14.186: D/qdmemalloc(31390): ion: Unmap buf  base:0x6cb1f000 size:4096
01-14 19:40:14.186: D/qdmemalloc(31390): ion: Unmap buf  base:0x6d9b7000 size:8355840
    01-14 19:40:14.186: D/qdmemalloc(31390): ion: Unmap buf  base:0x6cb4d000 size:4096
01-14 19:40:14.186: D/qdmemalloc(31390): ion: Unmap buf  base:0x6e3d8000 size:8355840
01-14 19:40:14.186: D/qdmemalloc(31390): ion: Unmap buf  base:0x6cb4f000 size:4096
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390): Activity com.example.apparty.MainActivity     has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41b092c0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,288} that was originally added here
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity     com.example.apparty.MainActivity has leaked window     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41b092c0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-    1026,288} that was originally added here
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>    (ViewRootImpl.java:394)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at     android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:239)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at     android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at     android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at     com.example.apparty.TabDiscotecas$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(TabDiscotecas.java:143)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at     android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at     com.example.apparty.TabDiscotecas.onCreate(TabDiscotecas.java:82)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at     android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5195)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2473)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2298)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:759)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at vandroid.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at     android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at     com.example.apparty.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:88)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5195)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2473)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2574)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1413)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027) 
 01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
 01-14 19:40:14.226: E/WindowManager(31390):    at     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i try declaring drawable[] imagenes too and there is no way... later i pass this to an adapter, what should i do?

Comment: show your doInBackground(), you are getting NullPointerException there !!

Comment: What is in line 195 in TabDiscotecas.java? Double-clicking the logcat line in eclipse will jump to the line where the error occured.

Comment: 195: imagenes.add(bmp);

Comment: have you initialized "imagenes" list ?

Comment: i just declare  ArrayList<Bitmap> imagenes; ane later .add(bmp) how i should init? it's necessary with arraylist? i'm learning sorry if it's a dumb question

Comment: now i declare private Bitmap[] imagenes=new Bitmap[20]; and works, but if i want an arraylist for dynamicly size, what should i do?

Comment: Did you initialise imagenes ?,if not do ArrayList<Bitmap> imagenes = new ArrayList<Bitmap>() before adding bitmap into arraylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because your URL is malformed (or some other error, possibly IO), which throws the error and skips where you assigned `bmp`, which remains null.

Comment: i try it with a code than works adding: ArrayList<Bitmap> imagenes; imagenes.add(bmp);and crash, but the image is well downlod because if i comment imagenes.add(bmp) the image it's showed with: imgLogo.setImageBitmap(bmp);

Comment: @user3137833 initialize imagenes to: `ArrayList<Bitmap> imagenes = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();`

Comment: No problem. When you just declare a variable but don't initialize it, the default value for all Objects is null. That's why you have to initialize it using the default constructor.